# Extension that is free to download but has a monthly payement

Tags: magento-1.9

I've seen this question asked a few times without a direct answer, hoping I can get some clarity.

If we build an extension thats free to download but charges a monthly fee, how does magento receive their revenue share? Do we bill the customer, collect payment then square up with Magento or is it he other way around?

Comment: I don't think so Magento bother about your " In Extension Purchase "

Comment: According to the documentation they do actually collect revenue share on all upgrades within the app if it was downloaded from the marketplace. What I am curious about is who audits this? Do we audit and send to magento or is it the other way around?